# Not able to run angular-cli command to build production

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have an Angular app, when I build this app in development environment (`npm run build`) it works completely fine.

But when I try to build with production tag, it fails with this error:

> C:/Users/1234/app/src/$$_gendir/app/app.component.ngfactory.ts
>   (617,85): Property 'router' is private and only accessible within
>   class 'AppComponent'.

I know router is private (in below code), but how is it working fine for development instance, and none but AppComponent.html should be able to use that?

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})

export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private router: Router, private _cookieService:CookieService) {
        //some function
    }
}
```

Comment: SImilar issue reported here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15451

Comment: Do you access `router` directly in your template?

Comment: yes.. I am using router directly into the template app.component.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Production build is stricter and thus doesn't let you access private objects outside of scope. You app.component.html will not be able to access router directly. You could write a public function in your app component and call the private router from within.

Comment: Sorry for trouble..but can you please show how to achieve that..I am new to angular2

Comment: It depends what you wish to do.

In your component you could have onButtonClicked(){this.router.navigate("location");}. Then you have a button in your template that has (click)="onButtonClicked()"

Comment: No problem :) Enjoy